# How to improve finding Twin Primes

Tags: c, primes, gmp

So I'm using the GMP library on the C language in order to find Twin primes above a certain value. While I'm confident that my strategy would work, the problem becomes the fact that it takes an immense amount of time (I understand that it becomes difficult in finding primes the higher you get.) Is there a way to optimize the search? Here's a snippet of the code that I have:

```
    mpz_ui_pow_ui(a, base, exponent);
    mpz_nextprime(b, a); // b is the next prime number after a.
                         // c and d will be prime + 2 and
                         // prime - 2.

    /* Fortunate of fortunalities, mpz_nextprime gives the next
       prime greater than what one adds in! */
    /* We need to test if numbers are prime too. */
    while (al == false) {
        mpz_add_ui (c, b, 2);
        mpz_add_ui (d, b, -2);
        if ((mpz_probab_prime_p(c, 15) == 2) ||
            (mpz_probab_prime_p(d, 15) == 2)) { // Returns 2
                                                // if c/d are
                                                // definitely
                                                // prime.
            mpz_set(firstprime,b); 
            al == true;
            break;
        }
        {
            mpz_nextprime(b, b); // b is the next prime number
                                 // after a. c and d will be
                                 // prime + 2 and prime - 2.
        }
    }
    printf("first twin is: ");
    mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, firstprime);
    printf("\n");
    printf("second twin is: ");
    if (mpz_probab_prime_p(c, 15) == 2) {
        mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, c);
    } else {
        mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, d);
    }
    printf ("\n");
```

Comment: There are other methods of checking for large primes, such as the Miller-Rabin primality test, without exhaustively finding all lower primes.

Comment: You are ignoring the case when `mpz_probab_prime_p` returns 1 for both `c` and `d`.

Comment: mpz probab does Miller-Rabin.

Comment: I am not sure it is safe to pass `b` in both parameters of `mpz_nextprime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is a little odd. You don't test whether `b` itself is a prime, but test one or both of `b - 2` and `b + 2`. Then, if either of those is definitely a prime, you declare `b` is one of the twin primes.

`mpz_nextprime` may return a non-prime, since it is using a probabilistic algorithm.

@chqrlie is correct in pointing out that `b - 2` had already been processed by `mpz_nextprime`. The only edge case is if the first call to `mpz_nextprime` resulted in a number only one or two away from `a`.

Since you are willing to accept that `b` is only probably a prime, you should be happy if both are probably primes. So:

```
/* a won't be prime */
mpz_ui_pow_ui(a, base, exponent);

if (exponent == 0) {
    mpz_nextprime(firstprime, a);
} else {
    /* Handle the edge case of a - 1 and a + 1 being twins */
    mpz_sub_ui(b, a, 2);
    mpz_nextprime(firstprime, b);
}

for (;;) {
    mpz_add_ui(c, firstprime, 2);
    if (mpz_probab_prime_p(c, 15) > 0) {
        break;
    }
    /* Optimize out an mpz_set call, thanks @chqrlie */
    mpz_nextprime(firstprime, c);
}
```

Which would find *probably twin primes*. If you want at least one to be definitely prime, you can implement your own prime test, or add a `mpz_probab_prime_p` call for `firstprime`.

Comment: Why is the for loop for(;;)?

Comment: I get the break, I meant the conditional for the for loop

Comment: No conditional check is needed, since we are only interested in the `break`. `for (;;)` is the same as `while (1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've been wondering on how best to optimize searches better so this was a nice way to look into it. I completely missed out on the fact that next prime would make -1 invalid!

Comment: @BrettHale:It isn't clear that `mpz_probab_prime_p` will ever return 0 or 2 with higher iteration numbers. The doc just says higher iteration numbers will just increase the probability that a returned value of 1 is actually a 2. So the only way to be **certain** would be to implement your own prime test.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to test if **b - 2** can be prime, as **b** is the next prime greater than **a**. This should halve the time for your search.  Probably still way too long for very large numbers.

Comment: Base is 2. Exponent is 64. next prime finds the prime number after 2^64th.